# How to Enter Text in Contact form using selenium Webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
WebDriver wd = new FirefoxDriver();
wd.manage().window().maximize();
wd.get("http://www.arthritisspecialityclinic.com");
WebElement link=wd.findElement(By.linkText("CONTACTS"));
link.click();
WebElement Name = wd.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='contact-form']/fieldset/label[1]/span[3]"));
Name.sendKeys("sakthivel");
}
```

I've executed the above code for Enter text in NAME text box under contact Form in website..But the text is not typed in the specific field only shown Blank...No error also shown in web driver...Any one can help me to Fix this....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your xPath is wrong. You should select the `input` tag instead of the `span` tag. Try this:

```
WebElement name = wd.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id='contact-form']/fieldset/label[1]/input"));
name.sendKeys("sakthivel");
```

**Suggestion:** This would be a cleaner method to select the `WebElement`.

```
WebElement name = wd.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='name']"));
name.sendKeys("sakthivel");
```

Comment: Thanks it works...Let me know how to find the input tag in code for particular field..Is there Any tool is available?....I used firepath tool for the above code...

Comment: @sakthivelbaskaran - I use the `Inspector` from the Web console of Firefox to read the HTML of the specific DOM I require. And then manually generate the xPath for that element. Do give the answer a [green tick](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) since it has helped you. :)